# Reading a users gmail in Google app engine app

Tags: google-app-engine

I am the admin of a Google domain and I need to he able to read users emails in my php app. How is this possible? I have tried to use IMAP but it won't even connect. Is there something special that apps have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of all the ways to read a user's Gmail mailbox, **outside of App Engine** :

- IMAP, as you said. Provided it is enabled on your domain. Most of our customers disable it for security reasons (no audit trace of the connections).
- [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/), but it requires the user's consent, even if you're an admin
- [The Email Audit API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/), but an Email extraction takes approximately 2 weeks (no kidding)

If IMAP is enabled on your domain, then it's the best choice. However, by default GAE does not allow outgoing connections apart from HTTP requests. The workaround for this limitation is the Sockets API, currently in preview. [You can check it out here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/sockets/).

Note that you will also need to use an [OAuth2 service account (domain-wide delegation)](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and [IMAP-XOAuth2 to authenticate](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol) with the IMAP protocol.

Comment: To avoid the appengine issue, do it from cloud compute instance.

Comment: App Engine does allow opening socket connections for paid apps.

Comment: Do i use the access token that client library generates for my service account or a different one. I have been able to connect using imap but I keep getting Invalid credentials.

Comment: See my last paragraph, you will need a service account and to implement x oauth2. It's not easy and if you're stuck i suggest you open a new question about it.

Comment: Then you need to implement X-OAuth2. Check those example codes from Google : https://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/downloads/list

Comment: I figured it out. I Wasn't getting the token string from the access token. It works now.